qcut is not finding quantiles (many 0s and 1s duplicated in my df)
I have a column of my df with MAX_PERC column ranging from 0 to 1.

The count of 0s are 103168.
The count of 1s are 32364.
The count of obs less than 1 and more than 0.8 is 2594.
The count of obs more than 0 and less than 0.8 is 129.

I'm trying to us pd.qcut to find quantiles it only works (i.e. finds more than one quantile) for higher quantile like (>0.8)
pd.qcut(df['MAX_PERC'],80,retbins=True, duplicates='drop')

To recreate the dataframe:
    # Define the counts
    count_zeros = 103168
    count_ones = 32364
    count_between_08_1 = 2594
    count_between_0_08 = 129
    
    # Create arrays for each range
    zeros = np.zeros(count_zeros)
    ones = np.ones(count_ones)
    between_08_1 = np.random.uniform(0.8, 1.0, count_between_08_1)
    between_0_08 = np.random.uniform(0, 0.8, count_between_0_08)
    
    # Combine all arrays
    all_values = np.concatenate([zeros, ones, between_08_1, between_0_08])
    
    # Shuffle the array to mix the values
    np.random.shuffle(all_values)
    
    # Create the DataFrame
    df = pd.DataFrame({'MAX_PERC': all_values})

Why? shouldn't be able to calculate quantiles at 2?

I was expecting to find more than one quantile in pd.qcut(df['MAX_PERC'],2,retbins=True, duplicates='drop'), since at least we have 0s and 1s. But it's not working that way. Cutpoints are, however, (-0.001, 1.0]

I'm not sure I understsand and I suspect some of your quantiles coincide with each other because they fall inside the ensemble of zeroes and ones, but please add this expected / unexpected behaviour inside your post for people to see it. This is an essntial part of the mre

To be clear: pd.qcut(df['MAX_PERC'],80,retbins=True, duplicates='drop') is the code that doesn't do what you want it to do? Exactly what happens when you try this code? Exactly what do you see instead, and exactly how is that different? "it only works (i.e. finds more than one quantile) for higher quantile like (>0.8)" It's impossible to understand this clearly. Are you saying, it should find more than one quantile, but does not? Or that it should not, but does? Or exactly what?

To answer this question exactly: (Why can't qcut produce quantile distributions with 2 bins in presence of a majority of duplicated elements?
Requesting 2 bins means split by median, yet the median is a zero :
df.quantile(q=0.5, 
            axis=0)

MAX_PERC    0.0
Name: 0.5, dtype: float64

But you already know this since count_zeros = 103168 is more than half your sample size (about 170'000 elements).
Those bins would be (0,0) and (0,1). Understandably, such requests cannot succeed. How did you expect this to work, is a mystery.

Yet work-arounds exist:

You could of course drop the duplicate elements but this is not what you seek.
Instead, now that I have looked at it in details, I confirm your question is identical to How to qcut with non unique bin edges?, which provides at least 2 interesting methods to produce a desired number of bins despite the presence of numerous duplicates. Both involve working on your dataset beforehand (ranking, noise). I won't plagiarise them here.

Other relevant reference: Trying to qcut an array of values into 4 bins - qcut is not friendly with duplicated data
